# Symfony 2 - separate form logic, show form errors after redirect

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to separate form validation logic:

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
            // .. setup a message and send it

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_demo'));
        }
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

I want to translate into 2 separate actions:

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}

public function contactSendAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
            // .. setup a message and send it using 

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_demo'));
        }
    }
    // errors found - go back
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'));
}
```

The problem is that when errors exist in the form - after form validation and redirect the do NOT showed in the contactAction. (probably they already will be forgotten after redirection - errors context will be lost)

Answer (score 5):

If you check out how the code generated by the [CRUD generator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html) handles this you will see that a failed form validation does not return a redirect but instead uses the same view as the `GET` method.  So in your example you would just:

```
return $this->render("YourBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig", array('form' => $form->createView()))
```

rather than return the redirect.  This means you do not lose the form errors as you do in a redirect.  Something else the CRUD generator adds is the [Method requirement](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) which means you could specify that the `ContactSendAction` requires the `POST` method and thus not need the extra `if($request->isMethod('POST')){` statement.

You can also just return an array if you specify the template elsewhere, for example you could use the [@Template annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) and then just

```
return array('form' => $form->createView())
```

Comment: thank you for information about method requirement and using return view instead of redirect. But if I'll use view instead it will be the same as it was - 2 logics are not separated anymore. Is there any way to use redirect and DO NOT loose form errors?

Comment: Redirecting and not loosing form data does not seem the right idea.  You could set the errors in the session and add them to the form but that is full of potential flaws. What are you trying to get away from by the logic separation?  You could potentially `return $this->contactAction();` if you wanted to?

Comment: Sorry my last comment about return $this->contactAction(); was me spit-balling and not well considered

Comment: unfortunately its not what I wanted to do. If there is no easy way to transfer form errors, then probably I would not separate these 2 logics. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me in Symfony 2.8:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller {
    public function templateAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $myBoundInstance);

        if ($session->has('previousRequest')) {
            $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType());
            $form->handleRequest($session->get('previousRequest'));
            $session->remove('previousRequest');
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    public function processingAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $myBoundInstance);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // do some stuff
            // ...

            return redirectToNextPage();
        }

        $session->set('previousRequest', $request);

        // handle errors
        // ...

        return redirectToPreviousPage();
    }
}
```

Please note that `redirectToNextPage` and `redirectToPreviousPage`, as well as `MyFormType`, are pseudo code. You would have to replace these bits with your own logic.

Comment: Interesting approach. Only downside I can see is you're processing the form twice if there are errors. Did you run into any other issues using the previous request in form extensions / listeners?

Comment: I haven't used form extensions or listeners so much with this validation approach so I don't have an answer for you, unfortunately.